# Is there a C or C++ equivalent to 'pass' in python?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a C or C++ equivalent to 'pass' in python? Also the same with break. For example:

```
while True:
    if x == 1:
        break
    else:
        pass
```

But in C/C++ instead?

Comment: `while (true) { if (x == 1) break; }` Just omit the `else` clause. You don't need one in your Python example, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a C or C++ equivalent to 'pass' in python?

Yes. There are actually two equivalents. One is the null statement:

```
;
```

Another is the empty block statement:

```
{}
```

These are in most cases inter-changeable except the null statement cannot be used in all cases where the empty block statement can. For example, the function body must be a block statement.

---

In the example case, you can omit the else-statement entirely just like you can in Python.

Comment: As a code reviewer I would say that if you do use the empty statement in C++ you are expected to note it is deliberately empty. `{/* deliberately empty */}` otherwise people get confused.